# Android Studio throwing "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I'm working on Android Studio and I've run into a simple but odd issue that I can't seem to solve. I've defined two string arrays as xml resource files, included below.

I've got a singleton class that acts as a controller where I try to populate two string array lists with those string arrays defined in the xml file. The compiler seems to have no issues with the code as written and even gladly offers those two string arrays as part of autocomplete. It's only when the code runs that I get the following error

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`

At this point I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, invalidating the cache and restarting AS, and I've also tried renaming the string arrays in xml and recompiling the code. Initially I'd created a new xml resource file to store those string arrays but currently I've moved them into the string resource file, but it hasn't worked either way.

None of that's worked and I'm just really confused as to what the issue could be. I appreciate any help you guys can offer. Thanks in advance.

Here's the relevant bit of the string xml resource file.

```xml
<resources>
    <string-array name="randomTriviaQuestionsArray">
        <item>As far as has ever been reported, no-one has ever seen an ostrich bury its head in the sand.</item>
        <item>Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.</item>
        <item>Popeye’s nephews were called Peepeye, Poopeye, Pipeye and Pupeye.</item>
        <item>In ancient Rome, a special room called a vomitorium was available for diners to purge food in during meals.</item>
        <item>The average person will shed 10 pounds of skin during their lifetime.</item>
        <item>Sneezes regularly exceed 100 m.p.h.</item>
        <item>A slug’s blood is green.</item>
        <item>The Great Wall Of China is visible from the moon.</item>
        <item>Virtually all Las Vegas gambling casinos ensure that they have no clocks.</item>
        <item>The total surface area of two human lungs have a surface area of approximately 70 square metres.</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="randomTriviaAnswersArray">
        <item>True.</item>
        <item>True – 52 bones in the feet and 206 in the whole body.</item>
        <item>True.</item>
        <item>False – It was the name for the entranceway to a stadium, nothing more.</item>
        <item>False – they will shed approximately 40.</item>
        <item>True</item>
        <item>True</item>
        <item>False – at a low orbit the Great Wall is visible, but no man-made structure is visible from outer space or the moon.</item>
        <item>True</item>
        <item>True</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Here's the bit of code where the error occurs at runtime.

```java
public void setupQuestionBank(String questionFileName){
        List<String> qList;
        List<String> aList;

  switch(questionFileName){
            case "randomTrivia":
                qList = Arrays.asList(Resources.getSystem()
                                      .getStringArray(
                                      R.array.randomTriviaQuestionsArray));

                aList = Arrays.asList(Resources.getSystem()
                                      .getStringArray(
                                      R.array.randomTriviaAnswersArray));
                break;
            default:
                qList = new ArrayList<>();
                aList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

EDIT: Here's the solution to this issue, thanks to DevMike01. Use a Context object of an activity or fragment to access the resource.

```java
public void setupQuestionBank(String questionFileName){
        List<String> qList;
        List<String> aList;

  switch(questionFileName, Context context){
            case "randomTrivia":
                qList = Arrays.asList(context.getResources()
                                      .getStringArray(
                R.array.randomTriviaQuestionsArray));

                aList = Arrays.asList(context.getResources()
                                      .getStringArray(
                                      R.array.randomTriviaAnswersArray));

                break;
            default:
                qList = new ArrayList<>();
                aList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the string array in a wrong way. Replace the `Resources.getSystem()` with `getActivity().getResources()` if you're in a fragment, but if the code is in an activity, simply call `getResources()` directly. Finally your code should look like this `...getResources().getStringArray(...);`/

Comment: Ok I see. This class is neither an activity nor a fragment, it's a singleton acting as a controller. Trying to find a way to reference those two string arrays in this class is actually what led me to the `Resources.getSystem()` bit but clearly that was a mistake. 

To do what you said I instead modified the method and ask for the context of the calling activity as an additional parameter. From there I followed your recommendation and use `context.getResources()` and it seems to work, so thank you! 

Quick follow up, any harm in using context instead of `getActivity()`?

Comment: Hmmm ok, in that case I'm curious why one gives an error and the other doesn't. Unless you meant there's no difference between `getActivity().getResources()` and  `context.getResources()`. 

And yep, that's exactly what I'm doing, I've modified the method so that it asks for the context to be passed in.

Comment: In most cases, there is no side effect as long as you're not making context/getActivity() static. Since its a singleton, you're probably injecting the `context` from somewhere that has it. Which is the same thing as calling the `getResources()` in the class that owns that context.

Comment: ok got it thank you!